# PictureBox doesn't display dynamically-generated Bitmap

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

In a Visual Basic .NET Windows Forms application, I am creating Bitmap objects from raw EGA data and trying to display them in PictureBox controls. It can create the objects fine, as I determined by using the Immediate window to call GetPixel. `SixteenColorBitmap` is a class from a library I am using.

```
Function TileImage(Tile As SixteenColorBitmap) As Bitmap
    Dim b As New Bitmap(32, 32)
    For y = 1 To 16
        For x = 1 To 16
            Dim t = Tile.Color(x - 1, y - 1)
            Dim c As Color = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(RGB(t.Item1, t.Item2, t.Item3))
            b.SetPixel((x - 1) * 2, (y - 1) * 2, c)
            b.SetPixel((x - 1) * 2 + 1, (y - 1) * 2, c)
            b.SetPixel((x - 1) * 2, (y - 1) * 2 + 1, c)
            b.SetPixel((x - 1) * 2 + 1, (y - 1) * 2 + 1, c)
        Next
    Next
    Return b
End Function
```

On loading the EGA graphics, that is called for each tile and the result stored in a list. When the user selects a tile, it should pull the right tile ID out of that list and assign it to the `Image` property of that PictureBox, like this:

```
TileBackground.Image = BackgroundTiles(SelTile(0))
```

(`TileBackground` is a PictureBox, `BackgroundTiles` is the list of GDI+ bitmaps, and `SelTile` is the array of selected tiles.) When that code runs, as I am sure it is doing, the bitmap is assigned to the property, but it does not display on the form, even when I call `Invalidate` or `Refresh`.

Comment: did you try `BackgroundTiles(SelTile(0)).Save()` instead to look at the generated Bitmap from disc for debugging purposes? that may clear up if it's really the picturebox misfunctioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did eventually get it working. As Jens suspected, something was wrong with the generated `Bitmap`, which was causing the `PictureBox` to freak out (silently) and not display it. The following code, for some unknown reason, works:

```
Function TileImage(Tile As SixteenColorBitmap) As Bitmap
    Dim b As New Bitmap(16, 16)
    For y = 1 To 16
        For x = 1 To 16
            Dim t = Tile.Color(x - 1, y - 1)
            Dim c As Color = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, t.Item1, t.Item2, t.Item3)
            b.SetPixel(x - 1, y - 1, c)
        Next
    Next
    Return b
End Function
```

Instead of manually doing the scale, I have the 32x32 control display my 16x16 image.